# Specifying Cross-Level Interactions in LMER

Tags: r, interaction, multilevel-analysis, lme4-nlme, nested-data

I am trying to figure out if it's okay to specify cross-level interactions in a hierarchical model with fixed effect predictor variables at both levels using the `lmer` function, and, if so, how to do it. I have asked a few other people and have heard varying responses, with some saying that I need to use a Bayesian approach while others saying that the frequentist approach using the `lmer` function in the `lme4` package would be fine.

My data are hierarchically structured with two levels. I have one site-level variable (elevation) and two annual-level climate variables (temperature and precipitation) to predict tree growth. The annual level variables (climate variables and growth) are nested within each site (24 sites total). Each site has about 2000 growth records, for a total of approximately 50,000 data points.

There are two ways I would think to write the model using `lmer`:

```
model1 <- lmer(growth ~ temperature*elevation + precipitation*elevation + (1|site))
model2 <- lmer(growth ~ temperature*elevation + precipitation*elevation + 
                        (temperature|site) + (precipitation|site))
```

Thus model 1 has a random intercept for site, and allows the effects of temperature and precipitation on growth to vary depending on elevation (my site-level predictor variable). Model 2 is similar, but has a random intercept for site as well as a random slope for site and the two climate variables.

For both models, I am a bit confused how the model knows that elevation is a site level predictor variable. Secondly, because I have cross-level interactions, would it be incorrect to specify model 1? My initial thought was to only use the random intercept for site with the cross-level interactions. However, in reading some of the very limited examples of cross level interactions with fixed effect predictor variables (e.g., JOM crosslevel [[pdf](http://www.hermanaguinis.com/JOMcrosslevel.pdf)], and [Model specification in nlme](http://www.rensenieuwenhuis.nl/r-sessions-21-multilevel-model-specification-nlme/)), I noticed that the examples provided included both a random intercept and random slope for the site level. When I compared the two models with my dataset, I noticed that the confidence of the `elevationXclimate` estimates were much wider (i.e., the SE for the estimate was much larger) in model 2 as compared to model 1. I am unsure if this is because model 2 is actually incorporating my hierarchical structure or if it is just because model 2 is more complex.

Comment: Neither OP or the only answerer has been active since 2014, suggest closing as this is complex enough that more back and forth is probably needed to determine what a reasonable answer is.

Answer (score 0):

I captured what you mentioned above that for the data is hierarchically structured with two levels with fixed factor one site-level variable (elevation) and two annual-level climate variables (temperature and precipitation) and as dependent is tree growth. Since the annual level variables (climate variables and growth) are nested within each site (24 sites total) so this each site will become your random factor.

With my experience works in mixed model, where LMER in R in also part of GLMM, I suggest you to use model 2 rather than model 1:

```
model2<-lmer(growth ~ temperature * elevation + precipitation * elevation + (temperature|site) + (precipitation|site))
```

where the important think in GLMM is that you should placed carefully the fixed and random factor in the model.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm still not sure though why I should use model 2 rather than model 1. If I were to use model 1 rather than model 2, would that then be pseudoreplication because it's not incorporating that elevation is a site level variable?