# Interactions between levels in lme4

Tags: r, interaction, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

We are implementing multilevel models in lme4 and have a question about how to handle cross-level predictors. This is a psychology experiment where individual participants come into the lab and complete multiple trials of the same task (e.g., judging how much they like a picture). To describe our dataset, we have trials nested within participants. These trials also have a trial-level predictor (e.g., how happy the participant rated they were before they made the judgment), and we might be interested in the relationship between happiness and liking (both rated on a 1-7 scale and treated as a linear variable). Modeling this with a random intercept for participant would be:

```
lmer(liking~happiness + (1|participant), data)
```

Now, in these data we also have three distinct races completing  the experiment (e.g., participants that self-identify as white-only, black-only, or hispanic-only). Each participant only belongs to 1 race, and each race contains multiple participants.

We hypothesize that trial-level happiness will interact with participant-level race to predict liking. To test this model, we believe lme4 will detect that race is a group-level factor (since only one value exists for each participant) and that we would run:

```
lmer(liking~happiness*race + (1|participant), data)
```

However, based on other reading, we're wondering if this should instead be treated as a nested or random slope. For instance, should we instead use:

```
lmer(liking~happiness*race + (1| race/participant), data)
```

or

```
lmer(liking~happiness*race + (1 + happiness | race/participant), data)
```

Again, we are interested in the interaction between race and happiness in predicting liking, and each participant only belongs to one race. Thank you in advance for your help!

PS: We have looked at [Specifying Cross-Level Interactions in LMER](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120517/specifying-cross-level-interactions-in-lmer) but this seems to represent a different data structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general principle here is that it only makes sense/is only possible to estimate within-level variation for factors that actually vary within that level in the course of the experiment/observation period.  Since happiness might vary within individuals across trials, but race can't, the maximal model you can fit would be

```
lmer(liking~happiness*race + (happiness|participant), data)
```

In other words, the effect of happiness on liking may vary across individuals; you will get estimates for

- (fixed) average effect of happiness on liking for the "baseline" race (whichever is the first level of your factor)
- (fixed) average effect of race (differences in liking from the baseline race) on liking for happiness zero (you might want to center happiness so that the 'zero' level of happiness is a more meaningful level [e.g. a baseline level of 4, or a baseline level of the mean happiness across the study population]
- (fixed) race-happiness interaction (the average difference in the happiness-liking slope between the baseline and other races)
- (random) among-individual intercept variation (difference in the expected liking of an individual at the baseline happiness from the expected liking for an individual of their race at the baseline happiness)
- (random) among-individual happiness-slope variation (difference in the expected effect of 1 unit of liking on happiness from the average effect for an individual of their race)

You could change the interpretation of the fixed factors slightly by changing contrasts.

To stretch a point a little bit, it might be possible in principle that the effect of race, or the happiness by race interaction, *could* vary across individuals, but you can't measure it. (This discussion would make more sense if considered in terms of a characteristic that is more likely to vary within individuals over some reasonable time scale but doesn't vary within individuals within the scope of the experiment.)